# Create Boolean column with values opposite to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following DataFrame in pandas:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 | New_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 82198 | True | False | False | red | True |
| 27498 | False | False | False | red | False |
| 84838 | False | False | True | red | True |
| 10498 | False | True | False | red | True |

I want to add another `New_column_2` with the opposite values to `New_column`:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 | New_column | New_column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 82198 | True | False | False | red | True | False |
| 27498 | False | False | False | red | False | True |
| 84838 | False | False | True | red | True | False |
| 10498 | False | True | False | red | True | False |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df['New_column_2'] = ~df['New_column']
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try:

```
df['new_column2'] = ~df['new_column']
```